# Banner and heading

Tags: css, image, banner

I just want to create image with title and button on top.

Text and button should be in container with set width. I just want to know what is the best way to do that.

There are lots of way that makes you confuse on internet and I don't know which one is best!

Comment: Your solution https://jsfiddle.net/bhushanwagh/xr1L5yob/

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If your background image has always the same aspect ratio, you can make the height of the container proportional to the width of the background image.

Let's say your background image is 2000 x 1000 px. And let's say the screen is currently 800px wide. Then you want the container with the background image to be 400px high. To achieve this without setting hard coded breakpoints, you can use the "padding trick". If you set the padding (top or bottom) of a child element in percent, it calculates the height as a percentage of the parent element's width. So if you set the the container's padding-top to 50%, it will be half as high as the the parent element is wide. So in the case of 2000 x 1000 px: 1000 / 2000 * 100 = 50%.

```
.parent_w_bg {
   background-image: url(...);
   width: 100%;
}
.container {
   width: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding-top: 50%; // Assuming the background image's aspect ratio is 1:2
}

<div class="parent_w_bg">
   <div class="container">
     Header and button etc.
   </div>
</div>
```

In such a scenario you should position the container relatively and it's children absolute, for example the header with a top value and the button with a bottom value.

Here a simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmcc5rnk/

Using multiple image sizes for different breakpoints can be useful, but also problematic. Depends on your specific case, the size of your image(s) and the amount of breakpoints you want to use (and the differences). Using different images according to some specified breakpoints is fine and can be used regardless of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a height for an entire section is never a good idea, unless specified in the project requirements. Always depend on the inner content to stretch your section vertically.

About the background - if you are using multiple images, you can apply different sizes and positions for them in one common background setting so that they can scale an re-arrange when the viewport resizes, or if you have one big image, you can simply set the image background size to `cover` like so:

```
background: url('images/image.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
```

There are many ways to achieve your goal, but the most up to date way of doing things is using the **[Flexbox model.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

All flexbox properties must be prefixed, so they can work across all browsers.

Explaining how Flex works is too broad for an answer, so you will have to learn it from the ground up.

Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yudgoddy/1/)** that represents your aim.

Answer (score -1):

```
No need to add different images for each breakpoint, 
image will resize automatically, you can add dynamic height by using jQuery
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/bhushanwagh/xr1L5yob/)